# Retrieve organisation's leads through oauth 2.0

Tags: rest-api, oauth2

I'm new to salesforce and to their API's so I'm a bit confused here:
I want to allow users of my platform to authenticate on their salesforce account through an oauth login and to then retrieve their leads to display in on a dashboard. I'm not talking about my organisation: I want other organisations to be able to authenticate, and then I'd like to be able to retrieve their data.

I read these posts:
http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-ruby

http://geekymartian.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-4-salesforce-oauth-implementation/

And both need the user to setup a r`emote access application`. 
Is there a way to avoid this step ? I'd like to setup a painless integration, without having the user do anything besides authenticating to salesforce on my platform.

I saw services doing this but I can't figure out how since every integration I read about requires a `client_id` or an `access_token` provided when a `remote access app` is setup.

Any input will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creation of connected app (Remote Access was earlier name) is one time process and not every user will have to do this .

For your Ruby app to oauth with salesforce or any other app to establish a secure session you cannot avoid creation of connected app .

This will be done by admin one time and generate client secret and client Id and your users will not have to worry about this process and they will just go through allowing access to the app by clicking few buttons .

Oauth is an industry standard and the process involves creation of client Id and client secret in the other app

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this work for other organisations ? 
I want my Ruby app to access other organisation's data, not mine. 
For example, if you have an organisation on salesforce, you'll be able to authenticate on my app and see your data through it. Will it work if I create a connected app myself ? Other organisations will not have to create one but I can still access their data ?

Comment: Thats correct .You can connect any org with connected app and you will be able to access their data